# Standard Normal Distribution and its generator

Tags: c++, random, generator, distribution

In the header:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <random>
#include <cmath>
// other includes...

class MyClass
{
public:
    int GetResult();
private:

    std::normal_distribution<double> *dist1;
    std::default_random_engine rand;
    int model_min, model_max;
    int model_mean, model_sd;
    int var1;
};

#endif
```

In the cpp

In an initialising function:

```
var1 = 1000;
model_mean = 30;
model_sd = 12;
dist1 = new std::normal_distribution<double>( model_mean, model_sd );
model_min = 10;
model_max = 100;
```

In a function to get a random result:

```
int MyClass::GetResult()
{
    int result;
    do {
        result = 0.5f + (*dist1)(rand);
    } while (result < model_min || result > model_max);

    result = result * var1;
    return result;
}
```

I call the initialising function once then GetResult() 1000000 times. After between 500 and 1000 times the results returned are 0.

I assume I am making a fundamental mistake with setting up and using the std::normal_distribution or std::default_random_engine.
After the 500-1000 calls to GetResult something strange happens to var1, and it gets set to zero. There are no places in the code where I alter var1 after its set to 1000.

Comment: Our of curiosity, where is your code to seed your `rand` default engine.

Comment: Except the strange way for constructing the distribution as a pointer I don't see any other problem with this piece of code. Nothing is changing var1 here.

Comment: Ok. The problem is fixed. No problem with the code above! Thanks

Comment: Whenever you fix a problem, it's usually a good idea to write what was wrong, in case someone else runs into it, however rare of a problem it wouldn't be.